# I can't figure out my pointer error

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am new to c.  I have a problem where I can't get two pointers to point to the same space in memory.  Here is some code.

```
struct IO{
    int val;
    char* name;
};

struct Gate{
    enum GateType type;
    struct Gate* next;
    int numInputs;
    struct IO* outputs;
    struct IO* inputs;
};
```

in the main I have

```
struct Gate* tempGate;
tempGate = (struct Gate*)malloc(sizeof(struct Gate));
struct IO* IOList;
IOList = (struct IO*)malloc(sizeof(struct IO)*20);

tempGate->inputs = (struct IO*)malloc(sizeof(struct IO*)*2);
tempGate->outputs = (struct IO*)malloc(sizeof(struct IO*));
```

later in a nested for loop we have this

```
tempGate->inputs[j] = IOList[i];
```

now when I change the value of IOList[i], shouldn't tempGate->inputs[j] change as well?  If not why?  How can I make this the case?  Help me Codiwan You're my only hope.

Comment: You know, Codiwan Can Know C. :)

Comment: Don't I need to allocate space for the pointers in tempGate->inputs even if they are pointing to the values in IOList?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. If you set two things to the same value, and change one of them, the other doesn't change. There is no "entanglement". (And your `malloc`s are returning pointers to pointers to `struct IO`, which you cast to pointers to `struct IO`. That is not good, it leads to undefined programs.)

Comment: Possibly unrelated to the problem you're experiencing, but [don't cast the return value of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/3488231).

Comment: `tempGate->inputs = IOList` will make those two pointers point to the same thing. Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make `inputs` and `outputs` arrays of pointers to `IO`, not arrays of `IO`. Then you can make the elements of this array point to elelemnts of `IOList`.

```
struct Gate{
    enum GateType type;
    struct Gate* next;
    int numInputs;
    struct IO** outputs;
    struct IO** inputs;
};

tempGates->inputs = malloc(sizeof(struct IO*)*2);
tempGates->outputs = malloc(sizeof(Struct IO*));
```

Then your loop should be:

```
tempGate->inputs[j] = &(IOList[i]);
```

Then when you change `IOList[i].val`, this will change the value of `tempGate->inputs[j]->val`.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted.  Thanks a bundle!